# Show a message from a page to another using PHP & HTML Form

Tags: php, html, email

I have an issue, i'm newbie and i don't think i've understand very well how should i do this ...

I have 3 files, contact.html, mail.php, afisare.php !!

**contact.html**

```
<form class="uk-form uk-form-stacked" method="post" action="mail.php">

                        <div class="uk-form-row">
                            <label class="uk-form-label">Your Name</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input type="text" name="nume" placeholder="" class="uk-width-1-1">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="uk-form-row">
                            <label class="uk-form-label">Your Email</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="" class="uk-width-1-1">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="uk-form-row">
                            <label class="uk-form-label">Your Message</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <textarea name="mesaj" class="uk-width-1-1" id="form-h-t" cols="100" rows="9"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="uk-form-row">
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php
$admin_email = "serbanalbertvasile@gmail.com";
$nume = $_POST['nume'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mesaj = $_POST['mesaj'];


if (!$nume ||!$email||!$mesaj) die ("Completati toate campurile!");

else {

echo "Numele: ".$nume."<br>";
echo "E-mail: ".$email."<br>";
echo "Mesaj: ".$mesaj."<br>";

echo "<p>Salut ".$nume."!<br>Mesajul tau: "".$mesaj."" a fost trimis la adresa ".$email.".</p>";

}


mail($admin_email, "Formular contact", $mesaj, "De la".$email);

?>
```

**afisare.html**

```
<div class="uk-vertical-align uk-text-center uk-height-1-1">
        <div class="uk-vertical-align-middle" style="width: 250px;">

            <img class="uk-margin-bottom" width="140" height="120" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="">

            <form class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-form">
                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <input class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-width-large" type="text" placeholder="Nume">
                </div>
                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <input class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-width-large" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <input class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-width-large" type="text" placeholder="Mesaj">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

What i want to do is to show in **afisare.html**, informations from **contact.html** using **mail.php**.

And i'm confused ... i do not think i fully understand how i can do it!

Comment: Explain what you mean show contact. Contact is just an html file, which isn't populated by anything?

Comment: Contact.html is a page where i complete info, like SENDER email, NAME of sender and MESSAGE of sender and i would like to print these in afisare.html using mail.php ...

Comment: It doesn't really work that way...you could set the action of contact.html's form to go to afisare, sending those $_POST variables, then running mail.php by including it?

Comment: Am i trying something impossible or stupid ?? I need some help here cause i got confused af ..

Comment: Could you explain me with an example a way to solve it ?

Comment: how are `afisare.html` and `contact.html` linked, if they are ? do they have to depend on each other ?

Comment: That is what i'm tryin' to do, to link them somehow after i press submit in contact.html to show informations from contact's form to afisare's form ... and i'm tryin' to do it by using mail.php in contact's form ...

Comment: I posted an answer,if you have questions let me know :)

Comment: so `afisare.html` is a response holder ? why put the response in inputs then ? I don't get the point in doing that ! you need to re-use data again after that ?

Comment: @OldPadawan well, i need it just one time, when i press submit in contact's form, i don't need or intend to re-use data again after i post it !

Comment: if so, I would go for Ajax : your form (contact.php) -> ajax call to mail.php -> response from mail.php back to contact.php -> handle response. You have many example on SO [contact + ajax + mail](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=contact+ajax+mail) or GIYBF ^^

Comment: @OldPadawan well, i've read some about ajax and what you've mentioned, but i'm in a smoke cloud atm and i'm reallyyyy confused ^^ !

Comment: @Albert-VasileŞerban : set up a quick example [HERE](https://pastebin.com/SmpG3wdT). Please check

Comment: @OldPadawan checked it, still got confused, i need to make it out using what i have, those 2 god damit html pages and that code from .php file ... i really need to work it out using those .

Comment: keep in mind that, unless you set up your server to do it (and in a very specific way and under some circumstances), *.html pages won't read php, therefore, on a regular server online, you won't be able to do what seems to be achieved, unless you put all into *.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way: 
Fill out contact.html...send variables and data to asfire.html run the mailer at the top of asfire.html

Change your file extensions to .php

Alternatively you could also do include 'email.php'; at the top of asfire.html like `<?php include 'email.php'; ?>`, instead of having the code at the top of asfire.html

Contact.html -> Contact.php

```
<form class="uk-form uk-form-stacked" method="post" action="asfire.html">

                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                                <label class="uk-form-label">Your Name</label>
                                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="nume" placeholder="" class="uk-width-1-1">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                                <label class="uk-form-label">Your Email</label>
                                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="" class="uk-width-1-1">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                                <label class="uk-form-label">Your Message</label>
                                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                    <textarea name="mesaj" class="uk-width-1-1" id="form-h-t" cols="100" rows="9"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="uk-form-row">
                                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                    <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

asfire.html -> asfire.html

```
<?php
$admin_email = "serbanalbertvasile@gmail.com";
$nume = $_POST['nume'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mesaj = $_POST['mesaj'];


if (!$nume ||!$email||!$mesaj) die ("Completati toate campurile!"){

else {

echo "Numele: ".$nume."<br>";
echo "E-mail: ".$email."<br>";
echo "Mesaj: ".$mesaj."<br>";

echo "<p>Salut ".$nume."!<br>Mesajul tau: "".$mesaj."" a fost trimis la adresa ".$email.".</p>";

}


mail($admin_email, "Formular contact", $mesaj, "De la".$email);

?>
<div class="uk-vertical-align uk-text-center uk-height-1-1">
        <div class="uk-vertical-align-middle" style="width: 250px;">

            <img class="uk-margin-bottom" width="140" height="120" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="">

            <form class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-form">
                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <input class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-width-large" type="text" placeholder="Nume" value='<?php echo $nume; ?>'>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <input class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-width-large" type="text" placeholder="Email" value='<?php echo $email; ?>' >
                </div>
                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <input class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-width-large" type="text" placeholder="Mesaj"value='<?php echo $mesaj; ?>'>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Also I fixed a { in your if statement, it was a ;

Comment: That;s awkward... i can't use it :) it doesn't recognise it as php in my .html file ...

Comment: i do not run it on xampp or something, i forgot to mention it

Comment: PHP won't run on it's own. It's a server language.

Comment: @i'm installing xampp atm, i will post a response in 2 minutes.

Comment: *.html pages can't execute *.php

Comment: Rename your files to .php @Albert-VasileŞerban

Comment: @clearshot66 i did that, i forgot to post it here, thanks in advance, i will mark your response as a solution, since your comm describe the solution i used for my problem. Thank you again, i will study harder than i did till now and i want to embrace this part of web development and design.